# SQL - Copy values from table and add new

Tags: mysql

We have a table `catalog_category_entity_text` with the following columns;

```
value_id - attribute_id - store_id - entity_id - value
```

For example with the following data;

6032 - 47 - 1 - 98 - VALUE TEXT EXAMPLE

Now we want to get all values from store **1** with attribute_id **47** and set value id with the next available value_id. Then the store_id must be set to **5** and entry_id and value should be copied from store **1**.

If the value for store_id 5 exist it should be overwritten, otherwise it should be added.

So the following row should be added:

6033 - 47 - 5 - 98 - VALUE TEXT EXAMPLE

Currently we have the following code, how can we complete this:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_text(value, entity_id, attribute_id, store_id)
SELECT value, entity_id, 47 AS attribute_id, 1 AS store_id
FROM catalog_category_entity_text
WHERE store_id = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have things backwards in your query. The values in the row you want to copy from should be in `WHERE`, while the new values you want to assign should be in `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_text(value, entity_id, attribute_id, store_id)
SELECT value, entity_id, attribute_id, 5 AS store_id
FROM catalog_category_entity_text
WHERE store_id = 1 AND attribute_id = 47
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. For some reason we then face the error: `Query 1 ERROR at Line 1: : Duplicate entry '551-47-5' for key 'catalog_category_entity_text.CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_TEXT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID'`. So it should replace value if exist and otherwise add new row

Comment: Use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists